# Generate <li> from array in <div>

Tags: javascript

Im geting **error** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null and i dont know why:

Im trying make a list from array and display it on div

```js
var options = [
    set0 = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'],
    set1 = ['First Option', 'Second Option', 'Third Option']
];

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:
document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(makeUL(options[1]));
```

```html
<div  id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: The snippet works for me?

Comment: It will work because of the included Stackoverflow libraries. If you create a HTML in your local and test, it will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will solve your problem

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = [
        set0 = ['Option 1','Option 2'],
        set1 = ['First Option','Second Option','Third Option']
                                    ];

        function makeUL(array) {
         // Create the list element:
        var list = document.createElement('ul');

        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         // Create the list item:
          var item = document.createElement('li');

         // Set its contents:
             item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

            // Add it to the list:
            list.appendChild(item);
                        }

            // Finally, return the constructed list:
                        return list;
                    }

            // Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:
            function DO()
            {
                document.getElementById("foo").appendChild(makeUL(options[1]));
            }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="DO()">
<div id="foo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason this error occurs is because the Javascript is executed before the Body of the HTML loads so it simply cannot find that div object. If you check via the developer tools document.body is going to be null right before your function executes. However, if you execute the function when the body loads then it will find the foo elem.